# Reading and appending to the same text file

Tags: python, file, pyserial, file-writing

I have a program that writes serial data to the text file. I want to check for specific card UIDs in the text file by reading the file at first, if there is already a card UID I want to skip the serial write step (serial write 0), if there isn't that card UID I will go ahead and serial write 1.

In order to check for card UIDs I have employed next command, please have a look at my code.

```
import threading
import serial
import sys
import io
import codecs
import queue
from pynput import keyboard

with io.open("uid.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as b:
    b.write("")

q = queue.Queue()
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 5)

class SerialReaderThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            output = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
            print(output)
            q.put(output)


class FileWriting(threading.Thread):
   def run(self):
       while True:
           output = q.get() 
           with io.open("uid.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as input:
               for line in input:
                   if line.startswith("Card UID: "):
                       s = (next(input))
                       if line.startswith(s): ***
                           ser.write(b'0\r\n')
                       else:
                           ser.write(b'1\r\n')
           with io.open("uid.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
               f.write(output)
                  

serial_thread = SerialReaderThread()
file_thread=FileWriting()

serial_thread.start()
file_thread.start()

serial_thread.join()
file_thread.join()
```

**FileWriting** thread is what I need help with. Again I want to first read the text file (which initially will be empty as it is created) and check for lines with card UID and look if there already is that specific card UID in the file if there is write 0 if there isn't write 1 in serial.

However running this code gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tsotne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Tsotne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\project\fff.py", line 36, in run
    s = (next(input))
StopIteration
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to check whether `output` is a `UID` held in the `uid.txt` file? And collect them all in the `uid.txt` file?

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you, I will try to explain better. The serial information is being kept in `uid.txt` file and there are many cards being scanned on the serial port each card has its unique card `UID`, I basically want to check if the card has been scanned already so the code won't allow to serial write 1 to the same card twice. I basically need to check in the text file if there already is specific card UID in the text file.

Comment: So why do you need a file? Could you hold the information in memory?

Comment: I just think this would be the easiest way to do it. But I will take any advice you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you re-create the `uid.txt` file empty each time you run your program, you don't need a file to hold the information. Just use a `set` instead:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 5)

class SerialReaderThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        uids = set()
        while True:
            output = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
            print(output)
            response = b'0' if output in uids else b'1'
            ser.write(response + b'\r\n')
            uids.add(output)

serial_thread = SerialReaderThread()

serial_thread.start()

serial_thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tested the code but it still writes `b'1\r\n'` to the same card when it is scanned, I will also post the serial output so maybe it will become bit more clear. This is the serial output and I want to check for UID however that code allows same card to write serial 1.

`Scan a MIFARE Classic


 FF FF FF FF FF FF


Card UID: F9 08 A3 99


PICC type:MIFARE 1KB


Authenticating using key A...


Writing data into block 22 ...


 00 2E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
`

Comment: The only thing that changes in serial between different cards is the `card UID` rest remains the same...

Comment: You need a way of extracting the card UID out of this data. I feel a new question coming on.

Comment: Not at all, I did what you said I reduced the data to only card UID and whether it was successful at writing 1 or not. this is my new serial data, however it still writes twice or more times to the same card and after 6 or 7 writes it only writes 0s to all cards.

`Card UID:  F9 08 A3 99




SUCCESS


Card UID:  F9 08 A3 99




SUCCESS
`

this is the serial output when putting same card twice to the writer.

Comment: Nevermind man I fixed it thank you so much for easing my job and helping fix my problem, all I did was reduce the data to only card UIDs and then it worked thanks a lot!